# Cannot find symbol error message in Java

Tags: java, string

Hi i'm getting the error:

> cannot find symbol - variable Andrew for this method.

What do I need to change?

```
/**
* Create a method that says hi if the name is the same as yours and go away otherwise.
* 
* @author (your name) 
* @version (a version number or a date)
*/
public class String
{
public void greeting(String name) {
    String myName;
    myName = Andrew;
    if (name == myName) {
        System.out.println("Hi");
    }
        else {
            System.out.println("Go away");
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Please accept one of the answers as an answer to your question and upvote if it help you. It is the least you can do when somebody invests time in helping you out. You have asked six questions and received answers to them all, but never  accepted one of them.

Answer (score 2):

use `equals()` to compare String, `==` will compare reference, also there is no declaration of `Andrew`

Answer (score 1):

```
myName = Andrew;
```

There you are using `Andrew` which is not declared yet, so you cannot use it.

To be able use it you have to first declare (also initialize correctly to see correct result at runtime)

```
String Andrew;
```

like that before you use it.

One other problem is your class name `String`. In the method `public void greeting(String name)`, which `String` class do you mean, your own or `java.lang.String`.

Comment: In that case, it is recommended to have andrew start with a non-capital letter.

Comment: @MarchingHome: Yes, I was about to add that but there I was what to add and what not to. I think it's better for him to learn about the Java Naming Convention.

Answer (score 1):

```
String myName = "Andrew";
if (name.equals(myName)) {
    System.out.println("Hi");
}
```

**Better to do the comparison other way round e.g. `myName.equals(name)`** in place of `name.equals(myName)` since `myName` is not null for sure while `name` can be `null`, which will result into NullPointerException.

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
public class String
{
public void greeting(String name) {
    String myName;
    myName = "Andrew";
    if (name.equals(myName)) {
        System.out.println("Hi");
    }
        else {
            System.out.println("Go away");
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String myName;
myName = Andrew;
```

And what is `Andrey`? According to Java syntax, compiller expects it's a variable, but actually there is not such a variable. I suppose you want to write something like

```
String myName;
myName = "Andrew";//this is correct initialization
```